# Avoid Data Loss While Processing Messages from Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, file-writing

Looking out for best approach for designing my Kafka Consumer. Basically I would like to see what is the best way to avoid data loss in case there are any 
exception/errors during processing the messages.

My use case is as below.

[image]

a) The reason why I am using a SERVICE to process the message is - in future I am planning to write an ERROR PROCESSOR application which would run at the end of the day, which will try to process the failed messages (not all messages, but messages which fails because of any dependencies like parent missing) again.

b) I want to make sure there is zero message loss and so I will save the message to a file in case there are any issues while saving the message to DB.

c) In production environment there can be multiple instances of consumer and services running and so there is high chance that multiple applications try to write to the 
same file.

Q-1) Is writing to file the only option to avoid data loss ?

Q-2) If it is the only option, how to make sure multiple applications write to the same file and read at the same time ? Please consider in future once the error processor 
is build, it might be reading the messages from the same file while another application is trying to write to the file.

**ERROR PROCESSOR** - Our source is following a event driven mechanics and there is high chance that some times the dependent event (for example, the parent entity for something) might get delayed by a couple of days. So in that case, I want my ERROR PROCESSOR to process the same messages multiple times.

Comment: If you are using spark for consuming the messages then you can look into spark checkpoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've run into something similar before. So, diving straight into your questions:

- Not necessarily, you could perhaps send those messages back to Kafka in a new topic (let's say - `error-topic`). So, when your error processor is ready, it could just listen in to the this `error-topic` and consume those messages as they come in.
- I think this question has been addressed in response to the first one. So, instead of using a file to write to and read from and open multiple file handles to do this concurrently, Kafka might be a better choice as it is designed for such problems.

***Note***: The following point is just some food for thought based on my limited understanding of your problem domain. So, you may just choose to ignore this safely.

One more point worth considering on your design for the `service` component - You might as well consider merging points 4 and 5 by sending all the error messages back to Kafka. That will enable you to process all error messages in a consistent way as opposed to putting some messages in the error DB and some in Kafka.

**EDIT**: Based on the additional information on the ERROR PROCESSOR requirement, here's a diagrammatic representation of the solution design.

[image]

I've deliberately kept the output of the ERROR PROCESSOR abstract for now just to keep it generic.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Lalit, I was also thinking in similar lines initially, but in my case I don't want all of the failed message to be reprocessed by the ERROR processor again. My ERROR processor would ideally - 
alert the producing application if there are any messages which failed due to validation issues/parsing errors. And it should re-process the messages which failed due to dependency issues (eg. may be a dependent entity was late to arrive from source system). 
Also, I am expecting a lot of similar use cases in future, so would like the ERROR Processor to be a generic one.

Comment: Ok. Are you saying that your ERROR PROCESSOR will sit after your SERVICE component? And that every message will need to go through the processing in the SERVICE before being fed to the ERROR PROCESSOR?

Comment: If ERRPR PROCESSOR & SERVICE can sit in parallel then you can still achieve the generic capability by making ERROR PROCESSOR an independent microservice that consumes from that error-topic. If you plan to have this read through varieties of errors in future then this distinction can be made in the message header or the partition level that would enable the ERROR PROCESSOR to handle them differently.

Comment: I have updated my question to include the requirement of ERROR PROCESSOR..I am looking for the best option to handle errors - I want to make sure that there are no messages are missed from my side. Not sure moving to a database or moving to an error topic is the best option. If we go with ERROR  TOPIC option, in future, the ERROR PROCESSOR might have to process messages from 20+ ERROR topics; And also, the message needs to be processed multiple times by the processor;

Comment: Well, you need not create 20+ topics. You could instead  just write all the varieties of errors in the same topic. Then, let the error message have the logic to deal with all of them. I think that this would be a cleaner design in my opinion i.e. the SERVICE picks up the messages, processes them and send them to the DB and all the error messages go to the error-topic with ERROR PROCESSOR dealing with them. I believe this would fit into your event driven architecture as Kafka is designed for use cases like this.

Comment: Okay, what is the best approach to route messages from a consumer to another topic (error topic here) ? Should I need to use the producer api ?

Comment: Yes. You'll need to embed a Kafka producer in the Service component as well as the ERROR PROCESSOR if you'd like to publish the messages back to Kafka. As this is a pretty good candidate for a whiteboard discussion so I've added a diagram - it might make it a bit easier to point to the boxes and refine this design. :)

Comment: Writing producer in Consumer :) this was something I wanted to avoid.. may it's high time to introduce something like Apache Camel for Kafka systems :)

Comment: I see what you mean :) but if you look at it closely, then it isn't really a producer within a consumer but a microservice that embeds a consumer and a producer. Also, this is quite common and one of the apache project called flume has a component known as "Kafka channel" which is exactly what I've described i.e. a consumer + a producer. Here's the link to the source code - https://github.com/apache/flume/blob/trunk/flume-ng-channels/flume-kafka-channel/src/main/java/org/apache/flume/channel/kafka/KafkaChannel.java.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't commit the consumed message before writing to the database, then nothing would be lost while Kafka retains the message. The tradeoff of that would be that if the consumer did commit to the database, but a Kafka offset commit fails or times out, you'd end up consuming records again and potentially have duplicates being processed in your service.

Even if you did write to a file, you wouldn't be guaranteed ordering unless you opened a file per partition, and ensured all consumers only ran on a single machine (because you're preserving state there, which isn't fault-tolerant). Deduplication would still need handled as well.

Also, rather than write your own consumer to a database, you could look into Kafka Connect framework. For validating a message, you can similarly deploy a Kafka Streams application to filter out bad messages from an input topic out into a topic to send to the DB

Comment: I am not committing the offsets to DB, am relying on Kafka commit to track the messages. Also, ordering is not important in my case.. But kafka stream is an option I will explore, but please can you update the answer with some examples on the same.